# Are they homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem:

Check if the following figures are homeomorphic, with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2.$
[image]

I believe that are not homeomorphic, but I can't find an invariant that help me to show it. I tried with the invariant that consist in the number of connected components, but it doesn't work. I hope you can help me. I'm a fool with topology.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide additional context to your question (e.g. what have you done).

Comment: @EricTowers I saw that, but is that answer correct?

Comment: Doesn't matter: an incorrect answer there does not justify posting a duplicate question.

Comment: @AntonioHernandez Yes, the answer there is fine. Of course, there are things assumed known. For example, that cut-points must be mapped to cut-points in a homeomorphism. That the four points where the circles touch in each figure are the only cut-points. That the number of connected components is an invariant. That removing the two cut-points on the ends from the second figure and restricting the homeomorphism gives an homeomorphism with the corresponding image.

Comment: The argument then finishes with the observation that the restricted function is mapping a space with three components to one with four.

Comment: @Boxwood Thank you so much!!!!